# Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon

I have not used the Monero Wallet GUI (v.0.12.0.0) for MAC OS (10.13.6) for about 3 months. I try to connect -

"Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081
 Height: 1548149/1548149 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 857.62 MH/s, v7, up to date, 0(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 0m 0s
 2018-08-20 15:06:06.095      0x7fffa05e2380    ERROR   net.http    contrib/epee/include/net/http_client.h:456  Unexpected recv fail
Error: Problem fetching info-- rpc_request: 
 2018-08-20 15:12:52.899      0x7fffa05e2380    ERROR   net.http    contrib/epee/include/net/http_client.h:456  Unexpected recv fail
Error: Problem fetching info-- rpc_request: 
 Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081"

I downloaded the new version the Monero GUI - v.0.12.3.0. When I try to connect I get "Please check your wallet and daemon log for errors. You can also try to start monerod manually." After I go to the daemon settings,  I see the same " Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081"

I try to stop_daemon through the command:[image]

What should I do with this error?

Comment: Is this issue resolved? My first guess: Since it says `127.0.0.1`, I wonder, if you have a daemon running locally...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Unexpected recv fail" is typical of a timeout. There were a few relevant issues that got fixed since then, you should update to 0.12.3.0 and try with that. Or 0.12.4.0 if it gets released before you get to update, as it should be soon.

Comment: The user notes they already updated to 12.3: "I downloaded the new version the Monero GUI - v.0.12.3.0.". I suspect this is some other issue.

Comment: Ah, right. If the new error does not have "Unexpected recv fail", then it might be something else. Need to look at the log to see whether it is.

Comment: Yes! I already updated to 12.3

Comment: "Need to look at the log to see whether it is" - Thank you. 
How can I do it? I've never done this before. I user MAC OS (10.13.6)

Comment: @Jori, have you tried restarting the GUI (+ daemon)?